# Display bottom bar in Android from the beginning

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an app with a WebView and when it launches, users have to click twice:

the first one, the bottom bar of the system (which was hidden) shows up
and then the second one, the app finally has the focus in the WebView so the users can tap around the website.

This is becoming really annoying for the users of the app, and I am wondering if is possible to show up the bottom bar from the beginning, so in the first tap, the WebView has already the focus.

Is it related to the fact I have this code right at the start of OnCreate method?

```
this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: what bottom bar? the system bar or part of your website? post the code that you are using now. There is little we can do to help if you aren't willing to show us what is going on.

Comment: why are you setting your application to TYPE_KEYGUARD?

Comment: I don't really remember. But I have checked than even if I remove that nothing happens.

Comment: if you don't know why you are using it then you shouldn't be using it ;-) and those two lines of code alone should not cause the issue you are seeing. Post the rest of your Activity.

Comment: Ok, I solved it. This was causing it: mWebView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION); I just removed and it works. Thank you, FoamyGuy!